Question regarding the behaviour of UserDefinedType
I am a bit intrigued by the current behaviour of DataFrame/Datasets wrt UserDefinedType.
As my understanding goes,  encoders are used to serialize ( convert to sql types or more specifically catalyst types) and to deserialize ( convert the Rows back to application specific instances).
So with UDT, it has a defined sql type, which means that a UDT Object can be serialized/decomposed into more granular native catalyst data types.
so in that sense the expectation would be to see the schema definition contain the expanded sql types, instead of UDT.
And when we have obtained a dataframe, then the UDT Instance should be exposed as its underlying SQL Type fields.
The behaviour is unlike the above, that is schema contains UDT and Row object contain instances.
More over if I dig deeper, I see that LocalRelation is represented using DeserializeToObject when exposing underlying data, while creating dataframe. Which results in current behaviour of seeing instances.
Should not in case of DataFrame, the LocalRelation be wrapper by SerializeFromObject and create a NamedStruct..?
